# Saber se a página esta em segundo plano

Tags: php, javascript, html

É possível saber se a página do meu site está sendo visitada em segundo plano pelo o internauta? Existe algum código ou forma de o saber?

Comment: Em segundo plano? o que quer dizer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira antiga de fazer isso, que é também mais compatível com browsers antigos, é assim:

```
var focused = true;
window.onfocus = function() {
    focused = true;
};
window.onblur = function() {
    focused = false;
};
```

e assim a qualquer momento podes testar `if (focused) {` e fazer algo caso seja positivo ou negativo.

Podes combinar isso também com `document.hasFocus();` que faz basicamente a mesma coisa.

A maneira que se espera seja melhor, mas ainda é uma recomendação, apesar de estar a ser implementada em alguns browsers, é a API da [*Page Visibility*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) que tem eventos novos e duas novas maneiras de verificar com propriedades estáticas:

- `document.hidden`, que pode ser `true` ou `false`
- `document.visibilityState`

#### Sugestão de polyfill

Fica aqui uma sugestão que me parece cobrir ambos os casos de browsers antigos e detecta também a API nova que referi. Esta sugestão tem uma global `focused` que é atualizada a cada mudança de estado e também uma função que é corrida quando o estado muda. testei aqui e funcionou como devia:

```
var focused = true; // sempre atualizada
function visibilityHandler(state) {
    console.log(state); // vai registando mudanças
}
(function(cb) {

    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "hidden";
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "mozHidden";
        visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "msHidden";
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "webkitHidden";
        visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
    }

    if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof document[hidden] === "undefined") {
        window.onfocus = function() {
            focused = true;
            cb(focused);
        };
        window.onblur = function() {
            focused = false;
            cb(focused);
        };
    } else {
        document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
            focused = !focused;
            cb(focused);
        }, false);
    }
})(visibilityHandler);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2wa92to/

Comment: Se essa é a maneira antiga, qual seria a maneira atual? (Curiosidade)

Comment: @Fernando bem visto, esqueci de juntar, editei agora.

Comment: @Fernando juntei ainda mais uma edição, agora que o jogo de Portugal já está despachado.

Comment: Sergio, mas como eu uso essa função? E só inserir e chamar ela na minha página e pronto? NÃO PRECISO MODIFICAR MAIS NADA?

Comment: @valpmg ou fazes `if (focused) {` quando precisares de saber, ou colocas código que precise de correr quando o estado muda dentro de `visibilityHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se a "maneira atual" que o [@Sergio mencionou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/136443/20615) é essa, mas você pode utilizar a [Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/standards/history/page-visibility).

Não é suportado para todos os browsers, como mostra a tabela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) você possui um tutorial de uso (play vídeo quando a página está visível), e sua [live demo](http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/) mostra o funcionamento.

O código do exemplo da Demo é esse abaixo:

```
   // Inline code is for educational purposes. Best practice is to put your scripts in external files.
    // Based on the tutorial at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Set the name of the "hidden" property and the change event for visibility
    var hidden, visibilityChange; 
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
      hidden = "hidden";
      visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") { // Firefox up to v17
      hidden = "mozHidden";
      visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") { // Chrome up to v32, Android up to v4.4, Blackberry up to v10
      hidden = "webkitHidden";
      visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
    }

    var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");

    // If the page is hidden, pause the video;
    // if the page is shown, play the video
    function handleVisibilityChange() {
      if (document[hidden]) {
        videoElement.pause();
      } else {
        videoElement.play();
      }
    }

    // Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
    if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof document[hidden] === "undefined") {
      alert("This demo requires a modern browser that supports the Page Visibility API.");
    } else {
      // Handle page visibility change   
      document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

      // When the video pauses and plays, change the title.
      videoElement.addEventListener("pause", function(){
        document.title = 'Paused';
      }, false);

      videoElement.addEventListener("play", function(){
        document.title = 'Playing'
      }, false);
    }

})();
```

Apenas para conhecimento, existem alguns projetos com essa finalidade. O que eu conheço é o [ifvisibility.](https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js/)

Comment: Valeu pela dica  Randrade, vou dar uma estudada no developer.mozilla.